# href links are not detected in a index.ejs file

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I have a nodeJS-HTML application. The html file accepts a form and calls nodeJS function which processes some data and send back some info to the hrml file. I am using views to render the details that need to be posted.

My app.js has this line of code

```
res.render('index.ejs', { collection: data})
```

where data is in the JSON format

```
"Name": "Chegg",
"Description" : "In February 2018, the diet and exercise service <a href=\"https://abc/FAQ.html\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">ABC suffered a loss</a>.
```

My index.ejs looks like this

```
<% for(var i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {%>
                    <div>
                     <p align="left"><%= collection[i].Domain %> </p> <br>
                     <p align="left"><%= collection[i].Description %> </p> <br>
                     <!-- <td><%= collection[i] %></td> -->
                    </div>
                  <% } 
%>
```

Here everything is populated correctly expect the Description. The links are not hyperlinked - but plain text.

Is there a way I can show the hyperlinks?

Comment: use `-` instead of `=` to output the unescaped value.  `<%- collection[i].Description %>`

Comment: awesome. Thank you so much

Comment: @dimitristseggenes You saved my day. Your comment should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @dimitristseggenes hyperlinks works with `-` but not with `=`

Change

```
<%= collection[i].Description %>
```

To

```
<%- collection[i].Description %>
```